# How to make sure to get data from api in swift

Tags: json, swift, urlsession

I try to fetch some data from api and store the data in a userdefault, then in another func to use the value in the userdefault. But sometimes when I try to get the value in the userdefault, it has not been fetched from api because of the poor internet, so how can I make sure I can get the data before I execute the second func.

Or do you have any solutions?

Thank you guys

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions, it sounds like you are using them for something larger.

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. Generally user defaults is only for small things like preferences.

Comment: Look up “Swift async await” on Google. Or “Swift completion handlers”. Both can solve your problem, but it requires you to study these topics a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

There can always be conditions where you can fail a fetch. When you are executing your function that uses the data you were fetching you can first make sure there is any data at all, before manipulating it.
For slow internet specifically, you can check "retries" and retry mechanisms: [example](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/retrying-an-async-swift-task/)

One more thing, UserDefaults shouldn't be used for storing large data, it's typically used for storing some user preferences like colors, fonts, etc. (It's not encrypted - unsafe)

Comment: You meant shouldn’t

Comment: Yes, my bad, sorry. You shouldn't store large data.